Should Imputation Models be Cross Validated
I have a project where I am predicting the best schools based on a series of tests scores, teacher attendance rates, etc.  I would like to predict the best school to go to.  Some of the data is of course missing.  I would like to use mice based using a random forest to impute the missing data.
Likewise the question other methods of multiple imputation be cross validates such KNN?
The question is should the results of the mice algorithm be cross validated?
My reasons for thinking the cross validation should be employed:  The data used is from the full set.  Therefore a data leak occurs when the full set of data is employed.  We have no objective basis to by which we choose the number of iterations.
My reason for thinking that cross validation should not be employed:  The an iterating multiple forests effectively self validates by excluding randomly selecting values in the process of imputation.
